An Error in my python code from PYtorch library
I spent much time to solve this error, but I failed. I ask for a help with this type of error as I cannot run my code.

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\Moetasem\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll" or one of its dependencies.

I tried by many ways to solve this problem using the similar errors with someone else or from chatgpt. However, all of my tries failed.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
